# Date () comparison forcing unwrap in Swift

Tags: swift

I am wondering how to avoid `!` in the following implementation. `Date()` does not do comparison without force unwrap.

```
 let expiry = (Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970) + 3600).description
 let tData = TData(token: sasToken, expiration: expiryInSeconds)
 private var tExpiryDate : Date? = nil

 if (tData == nil ||
      tExpiryDate == nil ||
      Date() >= tExpiryDate!) {
      // TODO : alert here
       tExpiryDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -(5*60))
            .addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(tData!.expiration))
 }
```

Comment: don't... do... any of that.

Comment: sorry, I could get your comment.

Comment: And now your code contains a major bug, you are force unwrapping `tData` when it possibly can be nil (first part of `if` condition)

Comment: How should I handle it?

Comment: To me it looks like tData can not be nil from your code, otherwise you can not set tExpiryDate. So either change `tData == nil` to a requirement that `tData != nil` or have a (default) way to set tExpiryDate when tData is nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the last comparison to

```
Date() >= (tExpiryDate ?? Date.distantPast)
```

Comment: Is it `Date.distantPast` or `future`? Please check my updated question.

Comment: It doesn't really matter with your current `if` condition, this is only to avoid forced unwrap but will never be checked because of the earlier `tExpiryDate == nil`

Answer (score 2):

The other way around, NAND instead of OR

```
guard  tData != nil, let expiryDate = tExpiryDate, Date() < expiryDate else {
    // TODO : alert here
    return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always aim to unwrap optionals as early as possible. Ideally, your functions all small and specific enough that you could just `guard let tExpiryDate = tExpiryDate else { return }`

I would treat `tData` entirely separately. If it's not part of the  "is in the past" comparison, it shouldn't be in the same predicate.

There are several options which work, but they all read pretty badly:

1. You could use `Optional.map`:

   ```
   if tExpiryDate.map { $0 < Date.now } == true { ... }
   ```
2. You could use an `if let` to bind a name to the intermediate unwrapped value:

   ```
   if let tExpiryDate = tExpiryDate, tExpiryDate < Date.now { ... }
   ```

I would recommend making a helper, which makes the call code obvious:

```
extension Date {
    var isInThePast: Bool { self < Date.now }
}

if tExpiryDate?.isInThePast ?? true { ... }
```

The coalesce to `true` encodes the assumption that a `nil` date is considered in the past. You might need to change it to false if you want to treat `nil` dates as being in the future.